# Unable to open SpriteKit scene editor for .sks files larger than 2mb

Tags: xcode, sprite-kit

After upgrading the Mac OS Catalina and Xcode 11.2.1 I am unable to open .sks files for my iOS game in the Xcode Sprite Kit scene editor.

Has anyone else faced this issue or found a fix for it? I was updating an old game of mine but simply cannot open the sks file. Smaller files are no issue and open fast. Xcode does not crash, I just get an endless spinning wheel.

Comment: It is possible that there is something in it that is not converting properly to the new sks format. Does the SKS open in code? Do any warnings appear?

Comment: I can easily open it in code without any issue with no warnings. I opened the project on an old mac running Xcode 10.1 and OS X 10.14.5. All scenes which are larger than 2mb currently cannot be opened all others can.

Comment: All the files also run just fine which makes me think this is an Xcode issue not the file itself.

Comment: I am just thinking it is a conversion issue.   Did you try making new a 2mb scene in the new version of xcode?

Comment: I know when I would upgrade, I would get crashing issues because a feature changed, or a custom class was renamed that I may have missed.

Comment: I will try making a new 2mb scene in Xcode and see how it goes.